# How to calculate CIDR notation from entries in a routing table

Tags: networking, ip, subnet

I have some entries in a routing table that were created using longest prefix matching, and I have to use those entries to determine the a.b.c.d/x notation (CIDR).

This is an example entry:

`11001000 00010111 00010`.

That was calculated from the range

`11001000 00010111 00010000 00000000`
through
`11001000 00010111 00010111 11111111`.

I know the range is from IP addresses `200.23.16.0` to `200.23.23.255`, but getting the /x for the subnet # doesn't make sense to me. Anyone know how to properly go about calculating it?

Comment: how and where did you get the binary representation?

Comment: I first had a table of destination address ranges like the second set of binary numbers you see above (with the "through"), then I had to make a forwarding table using the longest matching prefix needed to forward packets to a link interface. That's why it isn't a perfect set of octets.

Comment: ok. so your problem is only to determine the `/x` part, right?

Comment: Yeah, I just don't know how to calculate that although everywhere I look assumes you know how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a subnet number is not of your interest then your task is simple. You count the digits in your entry. That's it. So, with your sample we have:

```
11001000 00010111 00010

8+8+5=21
```

The `/x` is `/21`

Comment: I had a feeling this was the approach, it just didn't seem right because it was too easy.

Comment: yes, that simple )